# Migrating code previously accessing a MySQL server to access a MS SQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

I have a small app that is composed of Java servlets and the database server is a MySQL server. Now I have to move to a new server which runs Tomcat(thank god!) but for database it has SQL Server running in its stack.

So is there a big change that I have to make in my servlets code or just changing the drivers in my servlets will do this change?

Comment: Just changing the drivers should be good enough.

Comment: One thing to note, some data types might be a little different.  Not sure if that's related to your question, but it caused a couple hiccups for us.

Answer (score 1):

If you were implementing your DAO or any kind of DB access layer by relying on clean JDBC, you shouldn't need to do anything but change the JDBC drivers (and the datasource's connection information, like the connection string).

Most likely, your only required change should be to switch a connection string formatted for MySQL to one formatted for SQL Server, ie:

- from: `jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database][?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]`

  see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
- to: `jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]`

  see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I hope this is easy as you point it out to be, I just came to know about this change today and I am worried that it shouldn't increase my dev time :(

Comment: The code has simple connection strings and making simple SELECT, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE

Comment: @Sana: That's the whole point of JDBC. If there's nothing particularly fancy, you won't need to change much.

Comment: Ya I make simple JDBC connection, no hi-fi hibernate stuff.

Comment: @Sana: then you should be fine. You just need to update the connection string's syntax from something like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/name` to something like `jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]` (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx )

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer once I am done with the migration, thanks for quick answers.